# Pandas dataframe: count consecutive True / False values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a boolean `True`/`False`-column "`Mask`" in a dataframe, e.g.:

```
Mask
True
True
True
False
False
True
False
False
```

Now I am trying to add a column with the count of the consecutive `True`/`False` lines, where `True` is a positive sum (counts of +1) and `False` is a negative sum (counts of -1), e.g.

```
Mask     Count
True     3
True     3
True     3
False   -2
False   -2
True     1
False   -2
False   -2
```

I tried it with `groupby` and `sum` but now I got a knot in my head.

Tried something like

```
mask.groupby((~mask).cumsum()).cumsum().astype(int)
```

(`mask` is the condition for the `True`/`False`) but this only counts the Trues and does a count instead of showing the sum.

Would really appreciate any suggestions!

Comment: Can you show what you tried? It might have been very close and just needs a small fix.

Comment: I really don't have a hot lead yet :( Tried something like 
mask.groupby((~mask).cumsum()).cumsum().astype(int)
(mask is the condition for the True/False) but this only counts the Trues and does a count instead of showing the sum

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get the group number of consecutive `True`/`False` by [`.cumsum()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html) and put into `g`.

Then, group by `g` and get the size/count of each group by [`.transform()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.transform.html) + [`.size()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html).  Set the sign by multiplying the return value (`1` or `-1`) of [`np.where()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html), as follows:

```
g = df['Mask'].ne(df['Mask'].shift()).cumsum()

df['Count'] = df.groupby(g)['Mask'].transform('size') * np.where(df['Mask'], 1, -1)
```

**Result:**

```
print(df)

    Mask  Count
0   True      3
1   True      3
2   True      3
3  False     -2
4  False     -2
5   True      1
6  False     -2
7  False     -2
```

Comment: Wow, thanks SeaBean, this does the trick! Will thoroughly chew on this to get the logic.

Comment: @RazzleDazzle  Welcome!  You can run each line and see the result.  Also can run each step from the last line to check the intermediate result.  I will also add more explanation in answer.